# Matlab arrayfun with array of elements that are [1x4 struct]

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have a array, 'MY_STRUCTURES_Array', with single row and N columns. Each element is a [1x4 struct].  I want to extract a numeric valued 'thisField' from each structure of each [1x4 struct] element.

The result I am looking for is a 4xN array of the values for each 'thisField' value, where each row in this result corresponds to a colum in the [1x4 struct].

The code I am using is this:

```
arrayfun(@(x) (x.thisField),   MY_STRUCTURES_Array);
```

Matlab returns the error

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

If I put the following in the command line,

```
MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}
```

I get a list of all of the fields of the [1x4 struct].

If I put this in the command line,

```
MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}.thisField
```

I get four answers, like this:

```
ans =

       1


ans =

       1


ans =

       1


ans =

       0
```

If I look at the size

```
size(MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}.thisField)
```

Matlab says "Error using size", so I see this is not an array. But I'm not sure what it is.

I am not sure how to proceed to get the 4xN array I am looking for.

UPDATE

Output from command MY_STRUCTURES_Array returns a row array of [1x4 struct].

Output from whos MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1} returns nothing

Output from whos MY_STRUCTURES_Array returns:

```
 Name                     Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

 MY_STRUCTURES_Array      1x103            1371136  cell
```

Output from whos MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}.thisField returns nothing

Output from MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}.thisField was shown in the original post.

Comment: Can you show the output from the following three commands: `MY_STRUCTURES_Array`, `whos MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}` and `MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}.thisField`?

Comment: @StewieGriffin - see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're accessing `MY_STRUCTURES_Array` as `MY_STRUCTURES_Array{1}` indicates that it's a cell array, so I'll answer based on that.

Say we have `MY_STRUCTURES_Array` as a cell array of struct arrays:

```
MY_STRUCTURES_Array = {[1x4 struct], [1x4 struct], [1x4 struct]}
```

It contains `N` elements (here `N` = 3). Each element is a struct array with 4 elements and various fields. We want to extract the value of field `foo`, which contains a single number.

```
out = zeros(4, N);

for it = 1 : N
    out(:, it) = [MY_STRUCTURES_Array{it}.foo];
end
```

`out(i, j)` now contains the value of `MY_STRUCTURES_Array{j}(i).foo`

EDIT:

Using `arrayfun()`:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) x.foo, cell2mat(MY_STRUCTURES_Array')')
```

This converts the cell array of struct arrays into a 2d struct array, then extracts field `foo` from each element.